# Issue with document on 'load' event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**First issue**

My script runs fine when it listens for a `click` event on the element with the id `share`. Instead of a `click` event, I want the script to fire up on `$(document).on(load)` event and get rid of the `share` button. But I have tried it and it isn't working. Any idea why it isn't firing up the modal script?

**Second issue**

The modal window should close when the user clicks the close button, but it doesn't. I have added `console.log` to all functions and they are fired up every time I click close which shouldn't happen. Any idea why it isn't closing?

```js
$(function(){
  var $content = $('#welcome-modal').detach();

    $(document).on('load', function() {
    modal.open({
        content: $content,
        width: 500          
    });
});
}());

 var modal = (function() {
 var $window = $(window);                                                           //store the window object
 var $modal = $('<div class="modal-window">');                                          //create markup for modal
 var $content = $('<div class="modal-content">');
 var $close = $('<button role="button" class="modal-close">close</button>');

$modal.append($content, $close);                                                //append content and close button

$close.on('click', function(e) {                                                //if user clicks on close button
    e.preventDefault();                                                         //prevent default behaviour
    modal.close();                                                              //close modal

});

return {                                                                        //add code to modal
    center: function() {
        var top = Math.max($window.height() - $modal.outerHeight(), 0) / 2;     //calculate distance from top   
        var left = Math.max($window.width() - $modal.outerWidth(), 0) / 2;      //calculate distance from left

        $modal.css({
            top: top + $window.scrollTop(),                                     //apply css positioning to the modal
            left: left + $window.scrollLeft()
        });
        console.log('center');
    },
    open: function(settings) {

        $content.empty().append(settings.content);
        $modal.css({                                                            //removed height so it's auto
            width: settings.width || 'auto'                 
        }).appendTo('body');

        modal.center();
        $(window).on('resize', modal.center);
        console.log('open');
    },
    close: function() {
        console.log('close');
        $content.empty();                                                       //Remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM.
        $modal.detach();
        $(window).off('resize', modal.center);
    }
};
}());
```

```css
.modal-window {
position: absolute;
z-index: 10000;
background: #fff;
padding: 1.5em;
clear: both;
overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-content {
border: 0;
}

#share span {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="share">
    <span class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></span>
</div>
<div id="welcome-modal">
    <h4>This is jibber title</h4>
    <p>A load of jibber jabber</p>      
</div>
```

Comment: Define what "isn't working" means? Did you get an error? If so, what was it? What line did it point to as the problem? What not just use the standard JQuery document.ready instead of load?

Comment: Also, please limit yourself to one question per question. Right now, someone could right a brilliant answer for your first question, and totally fail your second question. How should one vote on that answer? Q&A means single Q, single A (well, per person/solution anyway).

Comment: Apologies. When I say 'isn't working', I meant, when I had the event as a click event, I was able to click on the `share` button, and the modal and its content popped up. I then wanted to change the event to a load event. The modal didn't appear when the document loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first issue is that you have a `document.load` event handler being registered inside of a `document.ready` function that is self-invoking!

```
// When you pass a function to JQuery, that function is automatically
// executed when the DOM is ready. No need to self-invoke it.
$(function(){
  var $content = $('#welcome-modal').detach();

    // Since this code is already running when the DOM is ready
    // there is no need to make this code the callback for document.load
    modal.open({
        content: $content,
        width: 500          
    });
});
```

Comment: Yep.  Beat me to it.

Comment: Ahhh. Thank you Scott